# Unable to copy baseline profile output from device

Tags: android, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

I'm trying to generate a baseline profile for my app but I'm seeing the following errors:

```
:benchmark:connectedReleaseAndroidTest
java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_osx_aarch_64.jnilib
java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative_aarch_64.jnilib
java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/native/libnetty_tcnative.jnilib
Shell command failed (255): appops set androidx.test.services MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
No UID for androidx.test.services in user 0
```

The baseline test does run on the device but is unable to successfully copy the output file from the device:

```
started: startup(com.doximity.benchmark.BaselineProfileGenerator)
Moving /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.doximity.benchmark/BaselineProfileGenerator_startup-baseline-prof.txt to /sdcard/Android/media/com.doximity.benchmark/additional_test_output/BaselineProfileGenerator_startup-baseline-prof.txt
Pull Baseline Profile with: `adb pull "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.doximity.benchmark/BaselineProfileGenerator_startup-baseline-prof-2023-08-22-18-48-56.txt" .`
Moving /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.doximity.benchmark/BaselineProfileGenerator_startup-baseline-prof-2023-08-22-18-48-56.txt to /sdcard/Android/media/com.doximity.benchmark/additional_test_output/BaselineProfileGenerator_startup-baseline-prof-2023-08-22-18-48-56.txt
finished: startup(com.doximity.benchmark.BaselineProfileGenerator)
```

This baseline profile test previously worked before updating the Android target SDK and AGP versions:

```
config.target_sdk_version = 34 // was 31
config.compile_sdk_version = 34 // was 33
versions.android_gradle_plugin = '8.1.1' // was 7.3.1
versions.kotlin = '1.9.0' // was 1.8.10
```

I've tried a few different devices and emulators and see the same behavior.

Comment: I have the same issue ("No UID for androidx.test.services in user 0"), and cannot find a solution anywhere. Don't even know how to begin troubleshooting this.